# <td> size increases on adding div

Tags: html, css

I have a table and what i want to do is place a div in each of the the cells which will have 
overflow: hidden so that when someone hovers over the image, the div will come down. The problem is that by doing this the size of the  increases with increase in size of div. What to do? 
css:

```
.table{
position:fixed;
top:50px;
left:200px;
table-layout:fixed;
}
.table td p{
position:relative;
margin:0;
}
.table td{
height:250px;
width:240px;
overflow:hidden;
  }
  .table td div{
position:relative;
height:50px;
top:-100px;
left:0;
text-align:center;
z-index:2;
color:#CCC;

-webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
-moz-transition: top 0.2s;
-o-transition: top 0.2s;
-ms-transition: top 0.2s;
    }
    .table td img{
position:relative;
left:20px;
top:-5px;
height:200px;
width:200px;

    }
    .table td:hover div{
-webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
-moz-transition: top 0.2s;
-o-transition: top 0.2s;
-ms-transition: top 0.2s;

top:50px;
    }
```

sorry, the html is like this:

```
   <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td><div>description</div><img src="something.jpg" alt="Not Found"><p>Hello</p></td>
        <td><div>description</div><img src="something.jpg" alt="Not Found"><p>Hello</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using position: relative in td and position absolute in div, like this:

```
.table td{
    position:relative;
    height:250px;
    width:240px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.table td div{
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    top:-100px;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:2;
    color:#CCC;

    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.2s;
    -o-transition: top 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: top 0.2s;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2hU6W/

Comment: That's because div's content, when you have relative positioned element inside a container, it behave as a block with "mass", so it push the content around him and occupy space in the container, but absolute position behaves as a free element floting in the container, in order to keep the absolute positioned element positionate inside it's container, the container must have relative position defined, otherwise, the absolute positioned element will go outside it's contianer.